# get rows which have a higher date than a specific one in MM/DD/YYYY format

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sqldatatypes

sorry for asking a really amateurish question, but I am only beginning to learn oracle.

I need to extract rows based on a date column which is in MM/DD/YYYY format , but I can't formulate a proper query. I used to_date function too but no fun.

I need to extract rows from XTABLE where XDATE is higher than 10/21/2011 (MM/DD/YYYY)

```
select * from XTABLE where XDATE >= '10/21/2011'
```

doesn't work, neither does

```
select * from XTABLE where to_date(XDATE,'MM/DD/YYYY') > to_date('28/10/2011','MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Comment: What is the datatype of the column XDATE?

Comment: Can you try without the single quote

Comment: I see. I was reading this http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_compare_dates.htm

Comment: The only difference is the format of the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Columns of type DATE aren't stored in MM/DD/YYYY format: It's just presentation according to your current NLS settings.

Your query should be:

```
select * from XTABLE where XDATE >= date '2011-10-21'
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ for information on date and other 'datetime' literals.

Comment: You can see http://www.ixora.com.au/notes/date_representation.htm for how Oracle actually stores dates internally if you're interested.